# In python, is there a way to convert of list of integer-lists into a list of string-lists without creating a custom function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, map-function

Let's say that I have a list of integer-lists:

```
start=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

And I want to convert this into:

```
result=[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]
```

I could solve this issue by creating my own function.  Is there a way to solve it without a custom function?

```
def stringify(x):
     return map(str,x)

start = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

result = map(stringify,start)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it as pythonic as possible, I would write:

```
result = [[str(subitem) for subitem in sublist] for sublist in start]
```

IMO, it is always better to write the most readable code, and [list-comprehensions are sometimes faster than map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) in combination with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like this:

```
result = [map(str, lst) for lst in start]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know the array is regular (i.e., all rows have the same length) you can also do

```
result = numpy.array(start, dtype=str)
```

which of course however returns a numpy array, not a list.